# Displaying an image field with multiple values in a content type in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, imagefield

I have a content type in which i had added image field. I can successfully displaying my body content having multiple instances by using `$body = field_get_items('node',$node, 'body');
  foreach ($body as $body) {
  print $body['value'];` but unable to print bmy image field by this method>

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution by using `$image = field_get_items('node',$node, 'field_name');
   foreach ($image as $key=>$value) {
        $output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_name', $image[$key]);

print render ($output);`